# How can I run a node server with a next.js application?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm setting up a webapp in next.js that runs in parallel with a node express server which does some middleware work to interface with an API server.

I have everything working however I don't know how to make it all work together when making a npm run start. The only way it works is with a "node server.js" in one terminal and a "npm run start" in another.

I've tried to add a package.json script like this: 
    "start-server": "next start && node server.js"
but it only starts the next.js instance, and if I reverse the order then it only starts the node instance.

How do I make them both work so I can deploy this project?

Comment: Try `next start & node server.js`. There's also npm packages for things like this such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently.

Comment: Holy, thanks man it looks like I was adding an extra '&' and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Also since Next is a server-side package, you can build the next app to use your `server.js` code before deploying the server. 
like so:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const options = {
  ...
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen('8700', err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on Port 8700`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Install [Concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) npm package to your node dependencies.

   ```
   npm install concurrently
   ```
2. Add the following scripts to node server's package.json

   ```
   "frontend-install": "npm install --prefix frontend",
   "start": "node server.js",
   "server": "nodemon server.js",
   "frontend": "cd ./frontend && npm run start",
   "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run frontend\""
   ```

i am assuming that your next application is in a folder/directory called "frontend".
3. Add the following code to package.json of the nextjs application.

```
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

4. Now `npm run start` command to start node server and nextjs app together.